# Изменить значения строк в таблице из запроса

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица с одним строковым столбцом, полученная запросом

```
SELECT
    str
FROM /*код получения таблицы*/
```

ну или можно со счетчиком строки, если так удобнее

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS NUM, str
```

Нужно каждую вторую строку из str заменить на другую и вывести новую полученную таблицу. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Ну например так:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) MOD 2
            THEN str
            ELSE REVERSE(str)
            END
FROM source_table
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=65ca05feb5f33e213c2dfddce9588b8d)

Наличие ORDER BY в описании окна - обязательно, иначе "каждая вторая" окажется "какая попало".

---

Не обратил внимания на СУБД. Для PostgreSQL это будет так:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) % 2 = 0
            THEN str
            ELSE REVERSE(str)
            END
FROM source_table
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6ffa3c2cbde00b8a7ba2a219447cbe46)